# How to properly escape special characters (like - ') in SOQL queries from Java code?

Tags: java, regex, string, salesforce, soql

I have a Java class where I construct SOQL queries using `String` concatenation.

Is there any best practice which someone can suggest to escape SOQL special characters like single quotes?

Comment: well, there is String.escapeSingleQuotes() method for that.

ex:
c.lastname=String.escapeSingleQuotes(c.lastname);

Similar Question:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8505/how-to-use-the-escapesinglequotes-method

Comment: @ShailendraPatel I am looking for a Java code where the post talks about Salesforce Apex code.

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry, I misunderstood the problem, My bad.

Here is the solution:

1.Use prepared Statement.

```
String data="a'b";
String stmt = " INSERT INTO student (column_name) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement(stmt);
statement.setString(1,data);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

2.Escape the single quotes. Single quotes can be escaped by using double single quotes. ' --> ''

```
String data="a'b";
String changedUserString = userString.replace("'","''");
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO student (column_name) VALUES("
                        +" '"+data+"' )";
```

Comment: Are you sure this is SOQL?  Salesforce Object Query Language?

Comment: Either use String.escapeSingleQuotes method or backspace:
 \'Hello\' .

Comment: @ShailendraPatel, the OP is using Java bindings for Salesforce, and probably passing an SOQL string into the 'query' method of the Salesforce Enterprise wsdl.  I'm trying a similar thing.  I haven't come across any way of performing escaping on the Java side - I don't think the String.escapeSingleQuotes method is available to Java developers.  I'm expecting to have to write my own escaping method based on documentation here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm